# Filter objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I got an array like this:

```
const xx = [
  {
    name: "Alex",
    income: 324300,
    total: 3030000
  },
  {
    name: "Snake",
    income: 3433000,
    total: 34323000
  }
];
```

I want to check if the income is larger than 300000 and if it is then their name would be stored or logged.

This is what i have tried, i dont fully understand how it works so..

```
var f = {};
for (var i = 0, len = xx.length; i < len; i++) {
    f[xx[i].id] = xx[i];
    if(f[income]>=500000){
        console.log(xx[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `f` for? Your objects have no `.id` property, so `f[xx[i].id] = xx[i]` doesn't make much sense. Did you mean `f[xx[i].name]`? There's no `income` variable, so `f[income]` doesn't make sense, though there is an `income` *property* on each `xx[i]` object, so did you mean `xx[i].income` or `f[xx[i].name].income`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array.filter for filtering the array and Array.forEach for iterating over it to console.log or w/e you want to do with it.

```js
const xx = [
  {
    name: "Alex",
    income: 324300,
    total: 3030000
  },
  {
    name: "Snake",
    income: 3433000,
    total: 34323000
  },
  {
    name: "Wake",
    income: 4,
    total: 3
  }
];

xx.filter(function(x) {
  return x.income > 30000;
}).forEach(function(x){
  console.log(x)
});
```

Comment: Why does everyone seem to use `.map()` all of a sudden instead of `.forEach()` when the result is ignored? This is a really bizarre trend that's taking place.

Answer (score 1):

in ES5 you can use filter to to obtain an array populate with elements having total > 300000

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "Alex",
    income: 324300,
    total: 30000
  },
  {
    name: "Snake",
    income: 3433000,
    total: 34323000
  }
];
var result = data.filter(x => x.total > 300000);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) has been defined in [ES5.1, Sec. 15.4.4.20](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20)

Comment: Your comment "_in ES6 you can use filter..._" is wrong. The only reason your solution requires an ES6 compatible environment is the use of the arrow notation.

Comment: He's just saying that your suggestion that ES6 is required in order to use filter is wrong. It can be used even in older versions of JS.

Comment: OK so I can change my first sentence and write : "in ES5 you can use filter...".   That's it ?? I must admit I ve been coding in JS for just 6 monthes and it's difficult to know if it's JS 1 5 or 6

Answer (score -2):

Use **filter** for this
Check this snippet

```js
const xx = [
  {
    name: "Alex",
    income: 324300,
    total: 3030000
  },
  {
    name: "Snake",
    income: 3433000,
    total: 34323000
  }
];
xx.filter(function(item){
  if(item.income>324300)
    alert(item.name);
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That it an improper use of `filter`. Use `forEach`

Comment: Why is it improper?

Comment: The function you pass to filter is supposed to return a boolean value.